# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: page2

Tags: sqlite, kivy, python-3.7, kivy-language

I am attempting to write the content of a table named page2 to another table named page3 but I keep getting  sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: page2 although all the databases and files are in the same directory. I have tried many things seen online. When I use sqlite browser it sees the table: page2.

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import sqlite3 as sql

# Paths
path = 'C:\\Users\\USA GADGETS\\PycharmProjects\\App\\first_page.db'
path1 = 'C:\\Users\\USA GADGETS\\PycharmProjects\\App\\second_page.db'
path2 = 'C:\\Users\\USA GADGETS\\PycharmProjects\\App\\third_page.db'
path3 = 'C:\\Users\\USA GADGETS\\PycharmProjects\\App\\fourth_page.db'
path4 = 'C:\\Users\\USA GADGETS\\PycharmProjects\\App\\fifth_page.db'

# connections
conn = sql.connect(path) # conect to first page database
conne = sql.connect(path1)# conect to second page database
connec=sql.connect(path2) # conect to third page database
fourth_page_connec = sql.connect(path3) # conect to fourth page database
fifth_page_connec = sql.connect(path4) # conect to fifth page database

# Cursor
cur = conn.cursor() # First page cursor
curs = conne.cursor() # Second page cursor
curso=connec.cursor() # Third page cursor
cursoo=fourth_page_connec.cursor() # Fourth page cursor
cursoor=fifth_page_connec.cursor() # Fifth page cursor

# pass a query
cur.execute(""" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS page1(Month)""") # First Page Query
conn.commit() # First Page commit
curs.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS page2(Items)""") # Second Page Query
conne.commit() # # Second Page commit
curso.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS page3(Description text,Amount REAL)""") # Third Page    Query
connec.commit() # Third Page Commit
cursoo.execute(""" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS page4(Description text,Amount REAL)""")
fourth_page_connec.commit()
cursoor.execute(""" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS page5(Description text,Amount REAL)""")
fifth_page_connec.commit()

# Close connection

conn.close()
conne.close()
connec.close()
fourth_page_connec.close()
fifth_page_connec.close()


# declaration of properties to modify objects from my.kv
finances= ObjectProperty()
month=ObjectProperty()
jan_action=ObjectProperty()
feb_action=ObjectProperty
mar_action=ObjectProperty()
apr_action=ObjectProperty
may_action=ObjectProperty()
jun_action=ObjectProperty
jul_action=ObjectProperty()
aug_action=ObjectProperty
sep_action=ObjectProperty()
oct_action=ObjectProperty
nov_action=ObjectProperty()
dec_action=ObjectProperty

# declaration of properties of second page
income_action=ObjectProperty()
budget_action=ObjectProperty
event_action=ObjectProperty()
analysis_action=ObjectProperty
report=ObjectProperty()

class FirstScreen(Screen):
    def call_back(self,instance):

    conn = sql.connect("first_page.db")

    # Cursor
    cur = conn.cursor()

    # pass a query
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO page1(
                Month) VALUES (?)""",(instance.text,))

    # commit
    conn.commit()
    # Close connection

    conn.close()


class SecondScreen(Screen):
    def call_back(self, instance):
    conne = sql.connect("second_page.db")

    # Cursor
    curs = conne.cursor()

    # pass a query

    curs.execute("""INSERT INTO page2(
                        items) VALUES (?)""", (instance.text,))
    conne.commit()
    curs.fetchall()

    # committ
    conne.commit()
    # Close connection

    conne.close()


class ThirdScreen(Screen):
    desc_action = ObjectProperty()
    amount_action = ObjectProperty()

    def getFromIncome(self):
        connec = sql.connect("third_page.db")

    # Cursor
        curso = connec.cursor()

    # pass a query
    curso.execute("""INSERT INTO page3(
                Description,Amount) VALUES (?,?)""", (self.desc_action.text,self.amount_action.text,))
    connec.commit()

    curso.execute(""" INSERT INTO page3 SELECT Items FROM page2""") # This is where error is comingfrom
    # commit
    connec.commit()
    # Close connection

    connec.close()

class FourthScreen(Screen):
    budget_input_1 = ObjectProperty()
    budget_input_2 = ObjectProperty()

    def getFromBudget(self):
        fourth_page_connec = sql.connect("fourth_page.db")

        # Cursor
        cursoo = fourth_page_connec.cursor()

        # pass a query
        # curso.execute("""ATTACH DATABASE third_page AS page3""")
        cursoo.execute("""INSERT INTO page4(
                    Description,Amount) VALUES (?,?)""",
                   (self.budget_input_1.text, self.budget_input_2.text,))

        #cursoo.execute(""" SELECT * FROM first_page.db CROSS JOIN third_page.db""")

        # committ
        fourth_page_connec.commit()
        # Close connection

        fourth_page_connec.close()

class FifthScreen(Screen):
    event_input_1 = ObjectProperty()
    event_input_2 = ObjectProperty()

    def getFromEvent(self):
        fifth_page_connec = sql.connect("fifth_page.db")

    # Cursor
        cursoor = fifth_page_connec.cursor()

        # pass a query
    
        cursoor.execute("""INSERT INTO page4(
                    Description,Amount) VALUES (?,?)""", (self.event_input_1.text, self.event_input_2_input_2.text,))
    
        #cursoor.execute(""" SELECT * FROM first_page.db CROSS JOIN third_page.db""")

        # committ
        fifth_page_connec.commit()
    # Close connection

        fifth_page_connec.close()

class FinalScreen(Screen):
    pass


class UserIncomePage(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv=Builder.load_file("my.kv")

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you execute the `INSERT` statement you must [attach](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) the database that contains the table `page2`:

```
curso.execute("ATTACH DATABASE 'databasename.db' AS db2")
```

Replace `'databasename.db'` with the full path and database name and extension of the database that you want to attach.
If this path is stored in the variable `path1` then by also supping the name of the column `Description  of` page3`where the value of the column`Items`of`page2` will be stored:

```
curso.execute("ATTACH DATABASE '" + path1 + "' AS db2")
```

Then execute the `INSERT` statement like this:

```
curso.execute("INSERT INTO page3 (Description) SELECT Items FROM db2.page2")
```

Comment: Thanks man, It worked perfectly, you've saved me many hours of confusion.

Comment: But wait ooh, there is a new error :sqlite3.OperationalError: table page3 has 2 columns but 1 values were supplied. What can I do sir ?

Comment: `page3` has the columns Description and Amount. So you should provide 2 values in the INSERT statement. If you don't want to fill the column Amount then:  `curso.execute("INSERT INTO page3(Description) SELECT Items FROM db2.page2")`, but if you want a value like `0` then `curso.execute("INSERT INTO page3(Description, Amount) SELECT Items, 0 FROM db2.page2")`

Comment: I did curso.execute(" INSERT INTO page3(Description,Amount) SELECT Items FROM db2.page2) and it still gives the same error: table page3 has 2 columns but 1 values were supplied

Comment: @Simeoni this is not what I wrote in my comment, Check it again.

Comment: The issue sir is that I want Description And Amount To be in the table not just Description

Comment: Then supply a value for Amount too. This is why in my code in the comment I set `0`. You can change it to whatever value you want. The table page2 does **not** have a column amount so that you could do `INSERT INTO page3(Description,Amount) SELECT Items, Amount FROM db2.page2` so you have to hardcode the value for the column Amount in the insert statement.

Comment: This is what I want sir: page3 table already has 2 columns (Description and Amount) but I need it to add Items column from page2 into page3.

Comment: You need to add Items column from page2 into page3, fine. What about the column Amount of page3. Do you want to leave it empty?

Comment: No I don't want to leave it empty, I want amount to be there sir. When I run INSERT INTO page3(Description,Amount) SELECT Items, Amount FROM db2.page2. It generates sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Amount

Comment: What Amount do you want? The table page2 from which you insert the rows to page3 does **not** have a column amount so there are no values to be inserted for this column.

Comment: What I'm now saying is that table page3 has two colums Description and Amount Originally. Let me show the query that I used to create the two columns: curso.execute("""INSERT INTO page3(
                    Description,Amount) VALUES (?,?) """, (self.desc_action.text,self.amount_action.text))
        connec.commit()

Comment: Read my comments carefully. The table page2 **does not have a column amount**. When you insert rows from page2 to page3 there is only 1 column value to be inserted to page3. So the column Amount in page3 will be left empty unless you supply a hardcoded value like 0 or 100.

Comment: Okay I understand but this is the issue: Description and Amount are added to table page3 whenever the user presses a save button, so I discovered when i hard coded a value like 0, Amount was just being filled with 0 instead of user input while Description column is being filled by values from income whereas what I want is by the time I bring in the Items column from table page2 it should automatically be the third column that will be in page 3. So that page3 now has three columns (Description, Amount,Items).

Comment: My answer is about the problem in the question as you posted it. If you have now a new problem/requirement then post a new question where you explain what you want.

Comment: Maybe I'm the one making a mistake,from those codes above, I just want to copy items Table page2 column into Table page3. Do you have any idea sir?

Comment: Execute the code in my answer as it is now that I edited. This will insert the rows of page2 to page3. For anything else you can ask a new question.

Comment: i cant even be allowed to ask a new question now

Comment: From the results in my database, the items from page2 are just overiding Description in page 3 which isn't looking like the act of copying something.

Comment: Take some time and read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers/251399#251399